# Decrease heading level if entry is descendant in Redactor

Tags: templating, redactor

I am currently building a doc system with multiple levels. I have build individual entries, but I'd like to parse the whole documentation in one page. Currently, I'm doing it like this:

```
{% set pages = craft.entries()
                    .section('documentation')
                    .all()
%}

{% for page in pages %}

  {{ page.articleContent }}

    {% if page.hasDescendants %}

      {% set children = page.children.all() %}

      {% for child in children %}

        {{ child.articleContent }}

      {% endfor %}

    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Though, with Redactor, all h2 defined in deeper levels remain h2. Is there a way to detect if an entry is at level 2 or 3 and set all the headings to n-level?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could potentially use Twig's [replace](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/replace.html) filter to replace any instance of `h2` with `h3`. If for some reason that's not powerful enough, there's also the Retcon plugin which could work too - specifically the `change` method: https://github.com/mmikkel/Retcon-Craft/wiki/Change

Comment: Hey James, thanks for the comment. I was trying something with replace filter. I couldn't get something conclusive (yet). I will dig a bit further in that direction. In the meantime, I'll check the Retcon plugin :)

Comment: Hey James, I did some tests with this solution, it seems that replace filter returns a string. So I tried to wrap the content in a `{% html %}` tag. Unfortunately, with this tag, nothing shows up in the rendered page. Ever faced something like this?

Comment: Try using the `raw` filter

Comment: It worked! Thank you so so much :)